# Pandas set value in groupby

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...            'letters' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
...            'is_min' : np.zeros(9),
...            'numbers' : np.random.randn(9)
... })

    is_min  letters numbers
0   0       a       0.322499
1   0       a      -0.196617
2   0       a      -1.194251
3   0       b       1.005323
4   0       b      -0.186364
5   0       b      -1.886273
6   0       c       0.014960
7   0       c      -0.832713
8   0       c       0.689531
```

I would like to set the 'is_min' col to 1 if 'numbers' is the minimum value by column 'letters'. I have tried this and feel that I am close...

```
>>> df.groupby('letters')['numbers'].transform('idxmin')

0    2
1    2
2    2
3    5
4    5
5    5
6    7
7    7
8    7
dtype: int64
```

I am having a hard time connecting the dots to set the val of 'is_min' to 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the row labels to `loc` and set the column:

```
In [34]:
df.loc[df.groupby('letters')['numbers'].transform('idxmin'), 'is_min']=1
df

Out[34]:
   is_min letters   numbers
0       1       a -0.374751
1       0       a  1.663334
2       0       a -0.123599
3       1       b -2.156204
4       0       b  0.201493
5       0       b  1.639512
6       0       c -0.447271
7       0       c  0.017204
8       1       c -1.261621
```

So what's happening here is that by calling `loc` we only select the rows that are returned by your `transform` method and these get set to `1` as desired.

Not sure if it matters much but you could call `unique` so that you get just the row labels without repetition which may be faster:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('letters')['numbers'].transform('idxmin').unique(), 'is_min']=1
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work without having repeated values and then calling unique. df.loc[df.groupby('letters')['numbers'].idxmin().values, 'is_min'] = 1

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to set the 'is_min' col to 1 if 'numbers' is the minimum value by column 'letters'.

A perhaps more intuitive method is to calculate the minima per group of `letters`, then use group-wise `.apply` to assign `is_min`:

```
def set_is_min(m):
   df.loc[df.numbers == m, 'is_min'] = 1
mins = df.groupby('letters').numbers.min().apply(set_is_min)
```

In large dataframes, this method is actually 20% faster than using transform:

```
# timeit with 100'000 rows
# .apply on group minima
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop
# .transform
10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop
```

I ran a some [more benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/b1fe001041610f30862a) of various methods using apply and transform.